# Create a new form in delphi radstudio 10.4 firemonkey

Tags: forms, delphi

I work on this app for android and windows with Delphi firemonkey. It was running fine before android 11. Having updated the cellphone, the app is getting force closed. Failing to resolve the issue with newest sdk as well as manipulating the manifest file, I had to migrate to rad studio 10.4.

The app contains a button with the following code to create a new form which used to run just fine in rad studio 10.3. But in rad studio 10.4, with pressing the button, nothing happens and the form is not shown.
I was wondering if there is a newer or efficient way to create and show the form.

```
 Application.CreateForm(Tfrm01, frm01);
 frm01.Parent:=frmMAIN;

TRY
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    frm01.Show;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    frm01.ShowModal;
{$ENDIF}
FINALLY
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    FreeAndNil(frm01);
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    frm01.Free;
{$ENDIF}
END;
```

By the way, I have also tried the following code to create the new form with the same results:

```
frm01 := Tfrm01.Create(self);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TForm.Show()` is not modal, it exits immediately, so you are `Free()`'ing the Form before it can be displayed onscreen.  Use the `TForm.ShowModal()` method on both platforms, the overloaded version that takes a `ResultProc` as a parameter should work on Android. To free such a modal `TForm` when it closes, use its `OnClose` event, setting the `Action` parameter to `caFree`.  This is all explained in the documentation:

[Using FireMonkey Modal Dialog Boxes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Modal_Dialog_Boxes)

For example:

```pascal
procedure Tfrm01.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

```pascal
frm01 := Tfrm01.Create(Application);
frm01.Parent := frmMAIN;
frm01.ShowModal(
  procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
  begin
    // do something...
  end
);
```

Comment: Thank you mate, very helpful. solved the issue.